# Text *blocker* for blog posts? (javascript? php?)

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, replace

So I'm not even sure where to begin..

I've got a platform where people can post their own 'generated' blogs from other people.

It takes a bunch of info via a form action and outputs it to a wordpress blogpost format.

One of the fields in the body of the post contains this " [word] " without the quotes. (the word is different based on the input).

Is there a way I can turn [word] into something else (preferably a graphic) based on the the words? like... I dont know much about scripts and stuff, but I envision something like this...

if[word], output('wordimage.png')instead.

Any way to do that

Comment: do you want to replace [word] for an image or just append the image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for str_replace(a, b); my friend.

```
$filtered = str_replace("naughtyword", "<img src='censored.png' />");
```

Comment: I just now stumbled on something similar to this - still working on how to implement it, but thanks for the confirmation! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look @ this : http://www.cybergamerz.net/f62/114/php-function-replace-text-tags-smiley-images/ I would copy->paste code from there but my eyes are going to pop out thanks to their color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about BBCodes I believe. The BBCode for an image is typically `[img=url]`, where url is replaced by the images url.